# What could cause wrong EditText background color on Nook HD+ device?

Tags: android, styles, device

I have had two reports from Nook HD+ users that my android app using a Holo Dark theme does not show EditText colors correct: they appear with white text on white background, making it impossible to read. I have applied no custom styling and the EditText layout looks like this:

```
    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

Any idea what is causing this and if there are any work arounds? Could it be that the Nook does not support the Holo Dark them correctly? THanks in advance,

Comment: I have a customer that is having the same problem.  Have you found a solution yet?

Comment: Yes, it was related to a custom theme that did not "inherit" from the correct theme. This made it work: <style name="CustomTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme">